# codes to create a unclickable page in an index of flatiron theme of Squarespace

Tags: css, squarespace

I want to have a page which shows up in my index page but not clickable (so as an image block). can i achieve this by css or page header code injection? Does anyone know? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to find the id of the div you'd like to edit.

Using the squarespace flatiron demo as an example, the div is "yui_3_17_2_1_1405046742289_1089"

```
a#yui_3_17_2_1_1405046742289_1089 {

   /*disable the link */ pointer-events:none;
}
```

If you want to hide the text over the image as well:

```
#yui_3_17_2_1_1405046742289_1089 .wrapper {display: none;}
```

}